# When to call notify in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, ui-thread

Will `notify*` methods in [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) run view's callbacks in UI thread automagically or have I to explicitly switch from my job's thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you interact with a View in android you *must* do it on the UI thread. This includes recyclerviews and their adapters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your  RecyclerView.Adapter you should call method notify in UI thread.